# Autofac - dynamic instantiation: passing constructor manually

Tags: c#, autofac, instantiation, .net-4.8

I use dynamic instantiation in AutoFac:

```
   public class X: I_X
   {
      public X(String p1, String p2)
      {
          ...
      }
   }

   public class A: I_A
   {
      public A(Func<String, String, I_X> x_Factory)
      {
         I_X my_x = x_Factory("one", "two");
         ...
      }
   }
```

Autofac resolves this as expected.

But suppose I were to use this code in a DLL that is also used in parallel by other projects without AutoFac support: How would I need to prepare the parameter "x_Factory" for the constructor of "A" and pass it so that this works?

```
   var manual_x_Fac = <what has to be done?>

   var a_object = new A(manual_x_Fac)
```

I would be happy if someone could help me. Thank you

**EDIT:**

Sorry, but I forgot to mention that I am still forced to work with the .Net Framework 4.8. The language version is therefore C# 8.0 (7.3).

For it to really help, the solution should also work with vb.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a `Func` delegate for example using [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions):

```cs
var manual_x_Fac = (string s, string s1) => new X(s, s1);
var a_object = new A(manual_x_Fac);
```

For older versions of the compiler you will need to specify the delegate type exlicitly:

```cs
Func<string, string, X> manual_x_Fac = (s, s1) => new X(s, s1);
```

Which is even more convenient if you inline the parameter:

```
var a_object = new A((s, s1) => new X(s, s1));
```

**UPD**

VB.NET version can look something like the following:

```
Dim manual_x_Fac As Func(Of String, String, X) = 
    Function(ByVal s As String, ByVal s1 As String) New X(s, s1)
```

Comment: This does not seem to be possible in the language version I am using. I get the following error message.

"Error CS8400 The "derived delegate type" feature is not available in C# 8.0. Use language version 10.0 or higher."

Although I am working on VS2022, I have to remain on .Net Framework 4.8 for the moment. Is there an alternative solution for .Net4.8?

Comment: The next problem could be that the solution must also work with vb.net !

Comment: @Duke 1) _"Error CS8400 "_ -  just specify the type instead of `var` - `Func<string, string, X> manual_x_Fac = ...`, again  inlining  (i.e. skipping the extra variable) should work as is. 2) _"must also work with vb.net"_ - I don't see any problems there - something along these lines `Dim manual_x_Fac As Func(Of String, String, X) = Function(ByVal s As String, ByVal s1 As String) New X(s, s1)` (not a VB expert though)

Comment: It works. Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot. 
If you add this information in your answer above, I would mark it as a solution for other people who are interested

Comment: @Duke added to the answer.